# How GATE processes machine learning (text classification)?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, text-classification, gate

Taking the following sentence as an exmaple (gotten from GATE official tutorial slide:module 11 https://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may10/track-3/module-11-ml-adv/):

**I was told the item was in stock and next day delivery. After a couple of days i chased them to be told there was an error, none in stock. Chased again after a few days, still no stock then found out that they had billed me right from the beginning. So they have had my money for over a week - have no idea when they will have stock- and i have done all the chasing. Despite what others say in eight years of Internet shopping worst experinece to date bar none.**

When the whole sentence is tagged as an anntation and treated as an instance in GATE machine learning PR(the Batch Learning), how the GATE would process the learning process?

I have two guesses. One is the GATE automatically tags every words in the sentence with human-language meanings and collects these features to build a classification model. The other is GATE simply transoforms the sentence into a mathematically variable, like vector and trains the model according to linguist features, like how many nouns, adj, adv are used.

I am not sure which one is right or whether there will be another explanation for the process. Hope someone could give a confirmation or any releated information.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

GATE build a model based on your definitions in configuration xml file. Except instance type there could be annotations like Token(with features root,POS,..) or N-grams or your own annotations (with features) created by JAPE rules. Gate will use thee definitions and will build a model.

Comment: Thanks ashingel. But if the instance or my own annotation are phrase or sentence, will them be split into single words to conduct feature extraction for machine learning?